# Windows 10 USB port allocation

Tags: usb, port, com

In a production line PC, a device-under-the-test product is plugged in and allocated with a port number. Then unplugged and the comport disappeared from the device manager list.

When a new product is plugged in - it gets a different port number and so on.

It seems that each allocated port number is kept for a particular device.

Once getting into 256 ports, the PC does not connect to any more devices, as all the com port numbers had been exhausted, although at any given time there is only a single device connected.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: See https://windowsdot.com/to-remove-all-history-of-usb-drives-ever-connected/ . Have you researched this before asking it as a question?

Comment: Downvotes are not warranted in my opinion.

Comment: This wording is confusing, “In a production line PC, a device-under-the-test product is plugged in and allocated with a port number. Then unplugged and the comport disappeared from the device manager list.” This this PC using USB ports to test stuff? I can’t understand what else this could be.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Device Manager, as admin.
- Scroll down to "Universal Serial Bus controllers"
- Right click and uninstall all USB Root Hub and controller devices.

Note: If your mouse is connected via USB, it will stop working - same for your keyboard and any other USB device.  Use a PS/2 mouse if your system has one, or do this while connected to the system via Remote Desktop.

- Restart.
- Windows Plug and Play will redetect and reinstall the Root Hub and controller devices.  You may need to restart again.

See if that resets the COM port count.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1749721/167207).

Meanwhile, a solution had been found:

Windows 10 allocates a serial port number to any different device which is plugged into the PC, and stores it in the case that the same device will be re-plugged.

"Different Device" in this context means a different USB PID/VID (Product ID, Vendor ID) or serial number. As the connected devices are identical, with the same PID/VID, it is the serial number that is different. Windows 10 generates this number based on a UID (Unique ID) which is provided by the device MCU. Once this number had been disabled (firmware change) - the problem had gone.